# Google Drive: What combination of scopes lets an app read existing files but not have edit/delete privileges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I've found that with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope, my app can read all existing files (and their contents) in a Google Drive, but when I auth the app, it says that this scope can also *delete* files in the drive and I don't want to grant that.

I know that by itself `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` only allows the app to read files *created* by the app itself or especially granted access.

I've tried other combinations, but can't find one where the the app can read the contents of any file I can see, but can't delete anything. This is the closest I've come:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents`

Is there a combination that will achieve my goal?

Comment: have you tried `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`? Scope meanings can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not intending to create any files or save any data to Drive, then you have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` scope.

Note that this is a *restricted* scope that will grant your app with read-only access to the user's entire Drive, but it will also prevent your app from creating any new files or editing existing ones.

If you want your application to be able to access the entire Drive, and you're planning to release your app to the public, you should submit your application to a [restricted scope verification and security assessment](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-auth#assessment); otherwise your app will be limited to 100 users, and users will see a warning while your app is [unverified](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865).

---

Here's more information:

- [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs - Drive API, v3](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)
- [Additional Requirements for Specific API Scopes](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy#additional_requirements_for_specific_api_scopes) section in the [Google API Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy)
- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your needs, you should be eyeing `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`. This enables you to read the file metadata and content.

> Allows read-only access to file metadata and file content.

#### Resource:

- [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one if you have access to read and write to a file then you will also have access to delete that file.

Its how they have permissions setup.

[image]

If you don't want to upload and only download try drive readonly.
[scopes#drive](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)

Comment: But I don't need the app to write anything. I just need to it to be able to read the content of the files, no make any changes at all. Can that be achieved?

Comment: You could go with read-only access but your still going to have to download the file Drive doesn't have access to actually see the contents of a file.

Comment: The original: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive